# How can I set the value of a $scope variable when my application starts up?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-class="theme">
<head>
 ...
</head>

<body>
    <form>
       <button class="white-gradient glossy" ng-click="theme = 'darkBlue'">Blue</button>
       <button class="white-gradient glossy" ng-click="theme = 'black'">Black</button>
    </form>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(angular.element(document).find('html'), ['app']);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The buttons act as theme switchers to change my CSS and this works fine.

Here's my app.js

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router', 'admin', 'home', 'questions', 'ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider',
        function ($locationProvider, $sceProvider, $stateProvider) {
            $sceProvider.enabled(false);
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            var home = {
                name: 'home',
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'menu': {
                        templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/menu.html',
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: '/Content/app/common/partials/empty.html',
                    }
                }
            }
            $stateProvider
                .state(home));

        }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.theme = 'darkBlue'
    }])
    .controller('appController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$state', function ($scope, $resource, $state) {
        $scope.state = $state;
    }]);
```

I am trying to set the default theme (line 2 of the HTML) at startup to 'darkBlue'.

However this does not seem to work. When my application starts the theme is not defined.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why it seems to ignore the line `$scope.theme = 'darkBlue'` ?

Note I also tried the following and this does not set the theme either:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $state.transitionTo('home')

}])
.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$state', function ($scope, $resource, $state) {
    $scope.state = $state;
    $scope.theme = 'darkBlue'
}]);
```

Comment: It's important to consider how the `theme` scope property is being accessed elsewhere in the app; this was not part of the question. It's entirely possible that the code you listed is working, but the theme variable is not accessible or is otherwise getting shadowed by the nature of prototypal inheritance.

Comment: For now the theme is not being accessed anywhere else except by the two buttons and the initial setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original example, you're injecting `$scope` into the `run` function

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $state.transitionTo('home')
    $scope.theme = 'darkBlue'
}])
```

but `run` cannot inject `$scope` because it isn't run against any particular view or controller. You can, however, inject `$rootScope` (as you already are) and set the data there:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $state.transitionTo('home')
    $rootScope.theme = 'darkBlue'
}])
```

Prototypal inheritance will ensure that `theme` is available as a property on any child scope; however, you won't be able to *change* that value, because in JavaScript, writing to a property in this manner overwrites the property on the *child* object (e.g. setting `$scope.theme` in a controller would not propogate the change back up to the `$rootScope`, as you saw in your second example). See [this wiki article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance) for more information.

What you would most likely want to do is create a service to serve as the shared state between all the various places you want to access and change the data. You can find more information about services [in the Developer Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services) and as [a video tutorial on egghead.io](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers), but basically you can inject them into any number of controllers and the controllers share a *single instance* of the service. For example, it may look something like this:

```html
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ThemeController">
    <form>
      <button class="white-gradient glossy"
        ng-click="theme.set('darkBlue')">Blue</button>
      <button class="white-gradient glossy"
        ng-click="theme.set('black')">Black</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AngularApp")
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(angular.element(document).find('html'), ['app']);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Then, you can set up your service and inject it into controllers:

```
var app = angular
  .factory('theme', function() {
    var theme = null;

    // every time you inject `theme`, it will inject the same instance
    // of this object, which contains methods for getting and setting
    // the current theme
    return {
      get: function() { return theme; },
      set: function(t) { theme = t; }
    };
  })
  // we can set the default theme in a `run` function
  // by injecting it
  .run(function(theme) {
    theme.set('darkBlue');
  })
  // Here is the new `ThemeController` we created in the template, above
  .controller('ThemeController', function($scope, theme) {
    // bind `theme` to the scope so we can change it
    $scope.theme = theme;
  })
  .config( // rest of app config
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/bnAzp/

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer. For this application I only need to set the theme in the one place and that's on the main page and through the two buttons I have. If this is the case would I still need to use a service? I see you create a new .factory and you are setting in the .run.  Can you show me how I could fit this into the example in the question. For example how can I fit your .run(function(theme) {  into my own run in the question?

Comment: @Marilou Services are the cleanest way to share data amongst different parts of your app; you could probably make it work with `$rootScope`, but you may run into trouble down the road. As for using your own `run` function, just add `theme` as another parameter and add the `theme.set` call in it as well.